# Flutter - How to save audio as a file?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio

I am using :

- flutter_sound_lite to record some audio.
- and path_provider to get path of my phone.
- permission_handler

I am creating directories and a file with a specified path to put my recorded audio.

I wonder if i am not finding it or it doesn't get created.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter_sound_lite/flutter_sound.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound_lite/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';


class SoundRecorder {
  FlutterSoundRecorder? _audioRecorder;
  ModelApiShazam? modelApiShazam;

  bool _isRecorderInitialised = false;

  bool get isRecording => _audioRecorder!.isRecording;

  Future init() async {
    _audioRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();

    final statusMic = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if(statusMic != PermissionStatus.granted){
      throw RecordingPermissionException('microphone permission');
    }
    final statusStorage = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!statusStorage.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
    await _audioRecorder!.openAudioSession();
    directoryPath = await _directoryPath();
    completePath = await _completePath(directoryPath);
    _createDirectory();
    _createFile();
    _isRecorderInitialised = true;
  }

  void dispose(){
    if(!_isRecorderInitialised) return;

    _audioRecorder!.closeAudioSession();
    _audioRecorder = null;
    _isRecorderInitialised = false;
  }

  Future _record() async{
    if(!_isRecorderInitialised) return;
    print("Path where the file will be : "+completePath);
    await _audioRecorder!.startRecorder(
        toFile: completePath,
        numChannels : 1,
        sampleRate: 44100,
    );
  }

  Future _stop() async{
    if(!_isRecorderInitialised) return;
    var s = await _audioRecorder!.stopRecorder();
    File f = File(completePath);
    print("The created file : $f");
  }

  Future toggleRecording() async{
    if(_audioRecorder!.isStopped){
      await _record();
    }else{
      await _stop();

    }
  }

  String completePath = "";
  String directoryPath = "";

  Future<String> _completePath(String directory) async {
    var fileName = _fileName();
    return "$directory$fileName";
  }

  Future<String> _directoryPath() async {
    var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var directoryPath = directory.path;
    return "$directoryPath/records/";
  }

  String _fileName() {
    return "record.wav";
  }


  Future _createFile() async {
    File(completePath)
        .create(recursive: true)
        .then((File file) async {
      //write to file
      Uint8List bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
      file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
      print("FILE CREATED AT : "+file.path);
    });
  }

  void _createDirectory() async {
    bool isDirectoryCreated = await Directory(directoryPath).exists();
    if (!isDirectoryCreated) {
      Directory(directoryPath).create()
          .then((Directory directory) {
        print("DIRECTORY CREATED AT : " +directory.path);
      });
    }
  }


}
```

output excluding flutter_sound :

```
I/flutter (20652): DIRECTORY CREATED AT : /data/user/0/com.example.shazam/app_flutter/records/
I/flutter (20652): FILE CREATED AT : /data/user/0/com.example.shazam/app_flutter/records/record.wav
```

I press the button to start the record...

```
I/flutter (20652): Path where the file will be : /data/user/0/com.example.shazam/app_flutter/records/record.wav
```

I press the button to end the record...

```
I/flutter (20652): The created file : File: '/data/user/0/com.example.shazam/app_flutter/records/record.wav'
```

I don't find where this file is located even if i am following the path

Answer (score 1):

I founs the solution !

Just replace

```
    var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var directoryPath = directory.path;
```

by

```
    var directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    var directoryPath = directory!.path;
```